# How to use var ejs in function call javascript

Tags: javascript, html, object, ejs

I would like to know how to pass ejs var in a function in javascript

```
index.ejs
 <%- include('header', {trans: text}) %>

//header.ejs
<% var lang=<%=lang%> %>

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:" onclick="redirection(lang)">contact</a> // pass the var in function
    </li>

//help.js

    function redirection(val){
        console.log(val);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that your EJS program and your client-side JS program are **two different programs** (and generally run on two different computers).

You need to put the data somewhere it can be read by the client-side JS program. For example, a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Then the client-side JS program needs to read it.

---

*Aside*: `href="javascript:"` is not a useful URL to visit. This is a strong clue that you shouldn't be using a link. I'll use a button for the rest of this example.

*Aside*: Event handlers are better bound with JavaScript rather than HTML.

---

```js
function redirection(event) {
  const button = event.currentTarget;
  const lang = button.dataset.lang;
  console.log(lang);
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", redirection);
```

```html
<button data-lang="<%= lang %>" type="button" class="nav-link">
      contact
</button>
```

Note in this example the EJS won't run because I have no server to run it on. You can see the EJS source code logged in the demo instead.